# print saved weights of particular layer [Tensorflow]

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

i'm using Tensorflow 1.0 with python 3.5 in PyCharm
after executing [this](https://gist.github.com/dandelionmane/4f02ab8f1451e276fea1f165a20336f1#file-mnist-py) code, i got model(index, meta and ckpt file) saved at every 500th iteration. now to load the model which file do we need to point?
i wrote below code to load the ckpt(weights) file (with no changes made to above github code)

```
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5, 5, 1, 32]), name="conv1/W")
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[32]), name="conv1/B")

w2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5, 5, 32, 64]), name="conv2/W")
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[64]), name="conv2/B")

w3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3136, 1024]), name="fc1/W")
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[1024]), name="fc1/B")

w4 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1024, 10]), name="fc2/W")
b4 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[10]), name="fc2/B")
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "D:/tmp/mnist_tutorial/model.ckpt")
```

got following error

> W
>   c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for D:/tmp/mnist_tutorial/model.ckpt
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1021, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1003, in _run_fn
>       status, run_metadata)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in **exit**
>       next(self.gen)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
>
> pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for D:/tmp/mnist_tutorial/model.ckpt
>        [[Node: save/RestoreV2_1 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_1/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_1/shape_and_slices)]]

before training starts (in function definition of convolution layer), we can print weights of individual layer by :

```
 w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 1, 64], stddev=0.1), name="W")
 b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[64]), name="B")           
 init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
 with tf.Session()as sess:
      sess.run(init)
      print("weight type is ", w)
      print('bias type is', b)
      print("random generated weights are: ")
      x = tf.Print('conv/W:0', [w],summarize=1600)
      sess.run(x)    
      print("Generated Biases are: ")
      y = tf.Print(b, [b],summarize=64)
      sess.run(y)
```

if there many convolution and fully connected layers, how to load and print any particular layer's weights and biases from `*.ckpt` file, as the above method is not working

**Update:** made changes to code and updated error message

Comment: Not rename the ckpt files. Suppose the files are 'model.ckpt-2000.index' and 'model.cpkt-2000.data-00000-of-00001'. The path you should restore with saver is 'model.ckpt-2000', although there is in fact no such file. For reading variables, NewCheckpointReader is a good choice. You can check the code for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [inspect_checkpoint tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py) in the tensorflow repository to read checkpoints.

Comment: passed `saved.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001`  as parameter to `inspect_checkpoint.py`, got same above error. also tried passing `saved.ckpt.index` and `saved.ckpt.meta` didn't work

Comment: I believe you should pass the common path (in your case saved.ckpt).

Comment: default code at github was saving as model.ckpt, got below message..so i passed model.ckpt       `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for D:/tmp/mnist_tutorial/model.ckpt
  [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]`

Comment: What files are actually there? Pass as argument the name up to whatever they have in common.

Comment: i should have passed `model.ckpt-2000`  now its working ..also i had to define weights and biases of same shape before loading..

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem as yours, but I just resolved it by adding the model and its index file to the root directory same as the directory where the **.py you will run.
then you will meet some problem like "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)",that will be easily corrected.